# How do I combine puppeteer plugins with puppeteer clusters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, puppeteer-cluster

I have a list of urls that need to be scraped from a website that uses React, for this reason I am using Puppeteer.
I do not want to be blocked by anti-bot servers, for this reason I have added [puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth)
I want to prevent ads from loading on the pages, so I am blocking ads by using [puppeteer-extra-plugin-adblocker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra-plugin-adblocker)
I also want to prevent my IP address from being blacklisted, so I have used [TOR nodes](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/anonymous-web-scrapping-with-node-js-tor-apify-and-cheerio-3b36ec6a45dc) to have different IP addresses.
Below is a simplified version of my code and the setup works *(`TOR_port` and `webUrl` are assigned dynamically though but for simplifying my question I have assigned it as a variable)* .
There is a problem though:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const _StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
const _AdblockerPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-adblocker');

puppeteer.use(_StealthPlugin());
puppeteer.use(_AdblockerPlugin());

var TOR_port = 13931;
var webUrl ='https://www.zillow.com/homedetails/2861-Bass-Haven-Ln-Saint-Augustine-FL-32092/47739703_zpid/';


const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    dumpio: false,
    headless: false,
    args: [
        `--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:${TOR_port}`,
        `--no-sandbox`,
    ],
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
});

try {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 720 });
    await page.goto(webUrl, {
        waitUntil: 'load',
        timeout: 30000,
    });

    page
    .waitForSelector('.price')
    .then(() => {
        console.log('The price is available');
        await browser.close();
    })
    .catch(() => {
        // close this since it is clearly not a zillow website
        throw new Error('This is not the zillow website');
    });
} catch (e) {
    await browser.close();
}
```

The above setup works but is very unreliable and I recently learnt about [Puppeteer-Cluster](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster). I need it to help me manage crawling multiple pages, to track my scraping tasks.

So, my question is how do I implement Puppeteer-Cluster with the above set-up. I am aware of an [example(https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster/blob/master/examples/different-puppeteer-library.js](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster/blob/master/examples/different-puppeteer-library.js)) offered by the library to show how you can implement plugins, but is so bare that I didn't quite understand it.

How do I implement Puppeteer-Cluster with the above TOR, AdBlocker, and Stealth configurations?

Comment: maybe you can read this as reference https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster/issues/228#issue-530751635

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just hand over your puppeteer Instance like following:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const _StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
const _AdblockerPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-adblocker');

puppeteer.use(_StealthPlugin());
puppeteer.use(_AdblockerPlugin());

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    puppeteer,
});
```

Src: https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster#clusterlaunchoptions

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the plugins with `puppeteer.use()`

You have to use puppeteer-extra.

```js
const { addExtra } = require("puppeteer-extra");
const vanillaPuppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const StealthPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth");
const RecaptchaPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha");
const { Cluster } = require("puppeteer-cluster");

(async () => {
  const puppeteer = addExtra(vanillaPuppeteer);
  puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());
  puppeteer.use(RecaptchaPlugin());

  // Do stuff
})();
```